# How to take payment in Civi event

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

Is it possible to process card payment for an event direct in Civi event without completing a form on the website?

Answer (score 1):

About 2/3rds of the way down the page under "register a participant manually". http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/everyday-tasks/